# C: How to count the number of times a particular number occurs using an array

Tags: c, frequency

I have written a code which is meant to track the position of a randomly moving 'particle'. The idea is that it is meant to move one position at a time. The direction in which it moves is random. The problem I have is that I can track the number of times the 'particle' has been in a certain position except for a set of random numbers. I know that these random numbers are false because the numbers that are outputted are either too large or negative. I am new to programming and have a limited knowledge. Below is my code thus far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int randomInt(int max)
 {
  return (random(2)%max);
 }

main()
 {
  int i;
  int position=1,r=1; /*Position indicates the position of the particle
                        and r represents where the particle will move
                        next*/ 
  int L=10,M=20;/*L is the number of sites and M is the number of hops*/
  int seed,n,sum=0;
  int frequency[position]; 

  //setup the random seed generator
  printf("\nEnter your value of seed\n");
  scanf("%d",&seed);
  srandom(seed);
  printf("\nThe value of the seed is %d\n",seed); 

  for(i=0;i<M;i++) //This loops around the total number of loops.
   {
    printf("\nThe particle is at position %d\n",position);
    n=randomInt(2);/*This chooses either the numbers 0 or 1 randomly */

    frequency[position]=frequency[position]+1;
    printf("This position has been visited %d times\n",frequency[position]);

    /*Below represents the conditions which will determine the movement
      of the particle*/

    if(n==0)
     {
       r=1;
     }
    if(n==1)
     {
       r=-1;
     }
    position = position + r;
    if(position==0)
     {
      position=L;
     }

    if(position==L+1)
     {
      position=1;
     }      

    }

}
```

Comment: `frequency[j]` must be intialized to 0 ! And `frequency` is of length `1`...Since index starts at 0 in c, `frequency[position]` is out of the array. This triggers undefined behavior.

Comment: Do not ask the same question because your previous question was closed.

Comment: Should `random(2)%max` be either `random(max)` or `random()%max`, depending on the implementation of `random()`? Possibly with a `(max-1)` or `(max+1)`, depending ditto.

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear, but here some fix to you prog:

```
#include<stdio.h>                                                              
#include <string.h>                                                            


int randomInt(int max)                                                         
{                                                                              
    return (random() % max);                                                   
}                                                                              

main()                                                                         
{                                                                              
    int i;                                                                     
    int position=1,r=1; /*Position indicates the position of the particle      
                          and r represents where the particle will move        
                          next*/                                               
    int L=10,M=20;/*L is the number of sites and M is the number of hops*/     
    int seed,n,sum=0;                                                          
    int frequency[L];                                                          

    memset(frequency, 0, sizeof(frequency));                                   
    //setup the random seed generator                                          
    printf("\nEnter your value of seed\n");                                    
    scanf("%d",&seed);                                                         
    srandom(seed);                                                             
    printf("\nThe value of the seed is %d\n",seed);                            

    for(i=0;i<M;i++) //This loops around the total number of loops.            
    {                                                                          
        printf("\nThe particle is at position %d\n",position);                 
        n = randomInt(2);/*This chooses either the numbers 0 or 1 randomly */  

        frequency[position]=frequency[position]+1;                             
        printf("This position has been visited %d times\n",frequency[position]); 

        /*Below represents the conditions which will determine the movement    
          of the particle*/                                                    

        if(n == 0)                                                             
        {                                                                      
            r = 1;                                                             
        }                                                                      
        if(n == 1)                                                             
        {                                                                      
            r = -1;                                                            
        }                                                                      
        position = position + r;                                               
        if(position < 0)                                                       
        {                                                                      
            position = L - 1;                                                  
        }                                                                      

        if(position >= L)                                                      
        {                                                                      
            position = 0;                                                      
        }                                                                      

    }                                                                          

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with your code :

- The array `frequency` should be of length `L`
- The array `frequency` should be initialized

One advice : change the tests, just in case you come back and wish to increment or decrement by more than 1.

Here is a code that is compiled by `gcc main.c -o main`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int randomInt(int max)
{
    return (rand()%max);
}

int main(int  argc,char *argv[]){
    int i;
    int position=1,r=1; /*Position indicates the position of the particle
                        and r represents where the particle will move
                        next*/ 
    int L=10,M=20;/*L is the number of sites and M is the number of hops*/
    int seed,n,sum=0;
    int frequency[L]; 
    //initialization of frequency [can use memset()]
    for(i=0;i<L;i++){
        frequency[i]=0;
    }
    //setup the random seed generator
    printf("\nEnter your value of seed\n");
    scanf("%d",&seed);
    srand(seed);
    printf("\nThe value of the seed is %d\n",seed); 

    for(i=0;i<M;i++) //This loops around the total number of loops.
    {
        printf("\nThe particle is at position %d\n",position);
        n=randomInt(2);/*This chooses either the numbers 0 or 1 randomly */

        frequency[position]=frequency[position]+1;
        printf("This position has been visited %d times\n",frequency[position]);

        /*Below represents the conditions which will determine the movement
      of the particle*/

        if(n==0)
        {
            r=1;
        }
        if(n==1)
        {
            r=-1;
        }
        position = position + r;
        if(position<0)
        {
            position=position+L;
        }

        if(position>L-1)
        {
            position=position-L;
        }      

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Beware of this use of `rand()`. According to the documentation of `rand()` about `v1 = rand() % 100;` :

> Notice though that this modulo operation does not generate uniformly distributed random numbers in the span (since in most cases this operation makes lower numbers slightly more likely).

In particular, in your case, if `RAND_MAX` is even, the `position` will feature a light tendency to loop upwards...